# Unit-Test a function

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Consider the following code

```
public class MyClass
{

public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string SurName { get; set; }

public MyClass GetInfo()
{
    //Get data from database 
    ...
    return new MyClass(FirstName, SurName);
}
}
```

I want to unit test `GetInfo()` but can't seem to figure out how to actually test it. Would I create a mock of `MyClass` and then do something like `Assert.AreEqual(uinfo.FirstName,"John");`

Thanks in advance for your help and support

Comment: What are you testing? Are you testing your properties? Are you testing DAO? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: I strongly suspect that mocking `MyClass` is *not* the way to go, as an aside...

Comment: @Aron I want to test is my `GetInfo` function and check if it returns the values

Comment: Well you want to test your 'real' GetInfo() so the mocking would happen at the //Get data from database level, ie you'd have something that instead of hitting the real db would pull back mock data.  How you would do that depends on what is hidden in your //Get data from database setup

Comment: @tolanj I use `SP` to get data from a table

Comment: There are no interaction with other classes, and so nothing to mock. Why does your class have a shallow clone method?

Comment: @Code Databases make code untestable. This is a case of poor separation of concern. Your DAO should live in the DAL and your Domain objects should live in the Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetInfo_ClonesAllProperties()
{
    // arrange
    var myClass = new myClass() { FirstName = "John", SurName = "Smith" };

    // act
    var clone = myClass.GetInfo();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(clone.FirstName,"John");
    Assert.AreEqual(clone.SurName,"Smith");
}
```